# How is this compiler error possible, and is there a workaround?

Tags: typescript, function, promise, compiler-errors, return-type

I have a routine for rate-limiting, concurrency, retry and timeout which iterates over a series of async operations.

However, typing for this routine leads to a confusing situation when the return value of `fn` doesn't have the type of `ReturnType<typeof fn>`. I would like to know why it's happening and find a workaround.

The issue is present in this minimal `consume()` example below. It just yields the resolved values and the provided async functions (the functions may have metadata added by the user to identify the values, hence the Generic)...

```js
interface ResolutionEvent<AsyncFn extends () => Promise<unknown>> {
  eventType: "resolved";
  factory: AsyncFn;
  value: Awaited<ReturnType<AsyncFn>>;
}

export async function* consume<AsyncFn extends () => Promise<unknown>>(
  factoryIterator: AsyncIterator<AsyncFn>
): AsyncGenerator<ResolutionEvent<AsyncFn>> {
  for (;;) {
    const iteration = await factoryIterator.next();
    if (iteration.done) {
      return;
    }
    const factory: AsyncFn = iteration.value;
    // compiler error for `promise` assignment in line below:
    // Type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<AsyncFn>'.
    const promise: ReturnType<AsyncFn> = factory();
    const value: Awaited<ReturnType<AsyncFn>> = await promise;
    yield {
      eventType: "resolved",
      factory,
      value,
    };
  }
}
```

I would normally rely on inferred typing throughout this routine, but I have explicitly annotated the types of `factory`, `promise` etc. for debugging purposes. The only compiler error is the one shown, which demonstrates that from a types point of view `factory` is definitely an `AsyncFn` but its return value is not `ReturnType<AsyncFn>` !

Is there a workaround for this single line issue? The whole of the rest of my implementation holds together well. Crucially it is simple to reason about based on a single type (the type of the async fn).

Restructuring every type and function call to have `<T, AsyncFn extends () => T = () => T>` makes the whole library much harder to make sense of, and would add nothing.

For reference, the AsyncFn type must be preserved. I can't reduce it to just `T` as users are expected to add payloads to each AsyncFn according to their needs (e.g. an id or a sequence index) so that the eventual (shuffled) results they get back can be correlated with the operations that created them.

Below is a motivating example of the kind of specialisation of the `AsyncFn` type which needs to be preserved in the generic `ResolutionEvent` type. Extra data added to the function means the user can reconcile the async values as they are resolved...

```
const fn = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeout));
fn.requestId = requestId++;
yield fn;
```

I may have no choice but to restructure how a user passes a factory, and how generics are expressed but just using the function type itself would be a really simple and elegant option.

Comment: don't know why this doesn't work (I guess something to do with extending a function has no clear way to know what part exactly is extended and how) but how about https://gist.github.com/zapl/84edef6955ffcdab285440b8db95dc0e ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it! Yes I would like to follow your guidance but as per the question I actually do need the function type to be a generic so that extra metadata is preserved. When notifying the result the original factory function is passed back so the user knows which result it is.

Comment: I should modify the question so that this is explicit in the failing implementation too with `yield {result, factory}`

Comment: the function is generic and the function signature should be identical (unless you explicitly call it typed `consume<XYZ>()`) and preserve all the type information, but rather than making the entire `() => Promise<unknown>` a generic boundary, it only makes the `T` in `() => Promise<T>` generic which is what I think you need. You know all the bits besides `unknown` and that's exactly an unbound `T`. It's simply replacing `AsyncFn` where it appears with `() => Promise<T>` and simplifies the return / awaited types because you have that type within `T`, see updated gist from above

Comment: Thanks again @zapl but `You know all the bits beside unknown` is not true. I've added a further code example to clarify the need for the function generic. Preserving this minimal (optional) feature for users prevented me from flattening to generic value `T` in the first place.

Comment: Incidentally it does seem to be a limitation of Typescript, connected to the deferred resolution of conditional types (which is how ReturnType and Awaited are defined under the hood)... https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50826

Comment: OK combining the design direction you suggested plus explicitly declaring the (default empty) metadata payload may be a workaround. I'll post as a potential answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have had superficial success with explicitly declaring request metadata as it's own `Meta` type which is intersected with a function type (the eventual value `T` is then the only generic determining the function, as suggested by @zapl).

The shape of the resulting code is as below. Basically it gives up on using the function type definition itself, since there is too much complexity and a [typescript limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50826) preventing proper type inference from generic functions. However, the function can still be 'augmented' with request specific metadata according to the user's needs when consuming the results. Users who don't specify a Meta type fall back to no extra payload attached to the function (`Meta` becomes `Record<any, never>`)...

```
interface ResolutionEvent<T, Meta> {
  eventType: "resolved";
  factory: (() => Promise<T>) & Meta;
  value: T;
}

export async function* consume<T, Meta = Record<any, never>>(
  factoryIterator: AsyncIterator<(() => Promise<T>) & Meta>
): AsyncGenerator<ResolutionEvent<T, Meta>> {
  for (;;) {
    const iteration = await factoryIterator.next();
    if (iteration.done) {
      return;
    }
    const factory = iteration.value;
    const promise = factory();
    const value = await promise;
    yield {
      eventType: "resolved",
      factory,
      value,
    };
  }
}

const myFn = () =>
  new Promise<string>((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, "hello"));
myFn.requestId = "foo";
type MyResolutionEvent = ResolutionEvent<string, { requestId: string }>;

const event: MyResolutionEvent = {
  eventType: "resolved",
  factory: myFn,
  value: "resultstring",
};

const { requestId } = event.factory;
```

Comment: The worst bit about this solution is having to pass explicit generic types, so instead of `const fn = () => sleep(100); fn.requestId = requestId++` you have to introduce a type `{requestId:string}` that flies all over the place as the `Meta`. It will have to be passed explicitly. It can't just be inferred from the `const fn` and whatever you assigned to it.

Comment: Not sure this is actually different or working for your scenario but this here seems to work without explicitly typing: https://gist.github.com/zapl/84edef6955ffcdab285440b8db95dc0e#file-consume4-ts

Comment: Wow that's super-powerful, so having `&Meta` allows functions to be extended in general (without a compilation error) but the types pass through cleanly! I'll have to wait until next weekend to revisit this personal project but I'm definitely interested to see how this approach unfolds!